# Flutter and application bundle Google Play Store upload limit

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, android-app-bundle

I'm about to develop an app in Flutter that will have a lot of assets. I'm aware that Google Play Store has an APK upload limit of 100 MB. I read some stuff about app bundles but I'm not sure what are the limitations of that in regards to Flutter. I unpacked the AAB file and I can see that the assets are in the `/assets` folder.

Does that count in Google Play Store as an 'asset package' meaning I can store up to 2 gigabytes of those assets? Or do I understand this incorrectly? What is the 150 MB limit about?

Answer (score 1):

Per https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle:

> With Android App Bundles, the compressed download size restriction is now 150MB

That means that your App Bundle could be 300 MB, but if any given user will not have to download more than 150MB of data when installing your app from the Play Store, then your app will be accepted.

Note that the *download* size of an APK is different from the size on disk, it's the compressed size. Bundletool has a command `get-size` which allows you to calculate the download size for your App Bundle.

If you have a lot of assets, you can also consider using [dynamic delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/dynamic-delivery) or [dynamic asset delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/asset-delivery) to reduce the size of your app. They're similar in that they both allow to reduce the install-time size of your app by letting you download parts of your app separately at a later time. The assets delivery also has a useful mode "fast-follow" to download assets right after the app has been installed, allowing users to open the app while other assets are still being downloaded.

Hope that helps.